# minimum possible size of square field that there are 400 peoples in there with some requirements.

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Given 400 peoples that would attend an invitation in a square field. Let $d$ be distance of each other and $d \geq 2$, $r_p=0.5$ be the radius of each person.
Find the minimum possible size of square field so that that event can hold regularly.

Can anyone give some hint? I still not get the idea yet. Thanks for help in advanced.

Comment: [Circle packing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing)? See also [Circle packing in a square](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square)

Comment: ok solved. thanks.